# Using repackaged.org.apache.commons.logging.* for apache mime4j

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, log4j

apache mime4j uses apache-commons-logging, but app engine has a repackaged lib lives as com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.logging.*.

How can we redirect apache mime4j to use the repackaged lib?

( we cannot use apache-commons-logging on app engine, can we? )

Answer (score 2):

You should **not** be using `com.google.appengine.repackaged.*` library. They are not part of the official API and can go away anytime.

Comment: How should we use apache mime4j which requires apache-common-logging?

Comment: You should include apache-common-logging jar in your application: http://commons.apache.org/logging/download_logging.cgi

Answer (score 0):

mime4j 0.7.2 solved the problem, the core code doesn't rely on common-loggings.